# Is there a way to effectively clean a Smart Cover without causing damage?

Tags: ipad, macos, smart-cover

On my iPad smart cover (It's one of the polyurethane ones) there seem to be some spots of what looks like grease, it could be some sort of food grease or skin oil. What would be the best way to clean the cover without damaging it? I was thinking just a damp paper towel would be best, but I want to see what would be best before I tried.

Comment: you may have received old stock since the covers were updated with microfibre linings which reflect the colour of the cover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found ironicly that using a Microfiber cloth does the job and also cleans the microfiber inside part of the cover.

I find that when you use it as a stand the inside of the cover collects anything you are standing it on and will the put this dust/debris onto the screen when its closed.

To add to this looking at the [Apple website on Smart covers](http://www.apple.com/ipad/smart-cover/), the microfiber lining is the same colour as the polyurethane, yet the actual product is grey (just like in the video on the same page).

Comment: however if it is grease you will have a tough time, without using a strong detergent. the downside is that the deterget could also remove the dye in the polyurethane.